# jQuery UI Dialog in IE7 not calling ASP.Net MVC controller after 1st time

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-dialog

We are developing an application in ASP.Net MVC 3 using jQuery UI Dialog.

This is our generic dialog code:

```
var $loading = $('<img src="' + srcLoadingImage + '" alt="loading">');

$(aElement).each(function () {
    var $dialog = $(divTarget)
            .append($loading.clone());

    var $link = $(this).click(function () {
        $dialog
                    .load($link.attr('href'))
                    .dialog({
                        modal: true,
                        title: $link.attr('title'),
                        width: 350,
                        height: 240
                    });

        $link.click(function () {
            $dialog.dialog('open');

            return false;
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

which we call like so..

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    RTC.Utils.aDialog('#selectAccount', '<div class="span-9"></div>', '@Url.Content("~/Content/images/loading.gif")');
});
```

The problem we are running into is that in Firefox everything works great.. but in IE7 the controller is only ever called the first time you access it.  After that it seems to be using the original version.

Do you need to manually destroy the dialog for IE7 to work properly?  Any pointers on how I'd do so?

-- UPDATE --

We removed the One() as per ammura's suggestion but we still have the same problem.

We have also tried adding close: function(ev, ui) { $(this).dialog("destroy"); } after the height in dialog({ but with no effect.

Thanks,

Shane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell jquery to not cache ajax requests, as James H's answer shows. I've never been a fan of this as jquery will append a meaningless argument to the GET request. It feels hackish and possibly even bug prone to me.

I have found that adding `[OutputCache(Duration=0)]` to the action in question works for me. It forces a true GET for each AJAX call. In my case I never want this call to ever be cached, as the data changes often.

Comment: We applied the attribute and things started working.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to disable caching in the jQuery ajax options?

`$.ajaxSetup({cache: false}});`

GET requests ($dialog.load(..)) can be cached by any browser and Internet Explorer tends to do so.

Answer (score 0):

If by calling the controller only one time you are referring to the `$dialog.load($link.attr('href'))` line then that makes sense since you have it wrapped in a [one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) handler.  This will only ever execute once and then unbind itself so it won't go and fetch this content on subsequent calls.  If you are referring to another call to a controller then you might need to post more code.

Comment: You were right about that being a bad thing but removing it didn't resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
.load($link.attr('href') + ($link.attr('href').indexOf("?") == -1 ? "?" : "&") + "random=" + Math.random())
```

I am sure it can work.